# How to display Rule-Bassed Labeling in QGIS using PyQGIS?

Tags: label, qgis

I've made the descriprion of my labeling and after script running nothing has changed on my layer. But than I go to “Layer->Properites->Labels” I can see that “Rule-Based Labeling” is choosed and also I've got my labeling rule is active.

I can display my labeling manualy by few simple steps:

1. Open “Edit Rule” window.
2. Press “OK” and go back to “Layer->Properites->Labels”.
3. Press “OK” and “Apply”.

Now I can see my labels. Why it doesn`t work after sript running?
Where is my mistake?

So, my code looks like this (QGIS 3.4)

```
#Configure settings of displayed text
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal
settings.fieldName = ‘expression in string format’

...some text format description here…..

settings.setFormat(textFormat)
settings.enabled = True

#Create and append a new rule
root = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(QgsPalLayerSettings())
rule = QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule(settings)
rule.setDescription(‘Morning Difference’)
rule.setFilterExpression(‘filter exp in string format’)
root.appendChild(rule)

#Apply label configuration
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)

rules = QgsRuleBasedLabeling(root)
layer.setLabeling(rules)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

So, I expected to see labels, but nothing changed and there is no error in script running.

Answer (score 1):

I`ve found a mistake.

We have to set "isExpression" to QgsPalLayerSettings() object. We have to set 'True'. The example at the second row

```
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.isExpression = True
settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
```